# How to center a text of an edit box in Delphi7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am currently working on a BlackJack application in Delphi7 and I am trying to center the text of an edit box in order to later show the card value. I found this documentation (http://delphidabbler.com/tips/85) and now I am failing to properly implement it. I put the code from the link into "Unit2" and am now trying to call both functions on my edit boxes from "Unit1" to align their text. Whenever i try to call one of both functions it tells me that passed parameters aren't identical.
If you guys would be able to help me out, it would be much appreciated.

Here is the decleration of Unit1:

```
 unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button10: TButton;
    Button4: TButton;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;

[...]
```

Here the code of Unit2:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TMyEdit = Class(TEdit)
  public
    FAlignment: TAlignment;
    procedure SetAlignment(Value: TAlignment);
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
    property Alignment: TAlignment read FAlignment write SetAlignment;
  end;

implementation

procedure TMyEdit.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  case Alignment of
    taLeftJustify:
      Params.Style := Params.Style or ES_LEFT and not ES_MULTILINE;
    taRightJustify:
      Params.Style := Params.Style or ES_RIGHT and not ES_MULTILINE;
    taCenter:
      Params.Style := Params.Style or ES_CENTER and not ES_MULTILINE;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyEdit.SetAlignment(Value: TAlignment);
begin
  if FAlignment <> Value then
  begin
    FAlignment := Value;
    RecreateWnd;
  end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: We really don't need to see an epic list of button declarations. What we would like is you to identify the line of code that results in an error, and what that error is. Don't describe what the error says. Quote it verbatim. I removed your spurious tags. This is not turbo pascal.

Comment: @ David Heffernan there is no part at the moment that fails, as I do not even have any idea on how to even call the functions of Unit2 on Edit4 for example. When i try it either says: Undeclared identifier or not identical parameters. With my question i was seeking help how to use that function in general. Thanks for the help with the tags though!

Comment: What functions of `Unit2`? It exposes a class which you don't see to use. Perhaps what you are looking for is an interposer class. Or why not register the component?

Comment: @David Heffernan i meant the procedures in `Unit2`. I already tried it with just calling `CreateParams()` and so on but i can't figure out how to apply it to Edit4 or even what parameters it has to pass. Im still a beginner so I am not even sure if that makes any sense at all...what do you mean with register the component?

Comment: You don't call those functions. The framework does. What you need to do is to create instances of that control rather than `TEdit`, which is what your `Unit1` does. You need to read up about, and follow some examples and tutorials, on component authoring.

Comment: @David Heffernan could you give me a short example on what something like this would look like in this case? Also on what parameter type to use

Comment: No. There are many available online. You need to step back and learn some more before you can hope to succeed at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually using the `TMyEdit` class at all. That is why `Unit1` can't use the functionality of `Unit2`. `Unit1` is still using the standard `TEdit`.

You have two choices:

1. Move `Unit2` to its own package that registers `TMyEdit`, and then install that package into the IDE. `TMyEdit` will then be available at design-time, and you can replace the `TEdit` controls with `TMyEdit` controls.
2. If you don't want to go that route, the alternative is to redeclare `TMyEdit` to `TEdit` and leave `Unit1` as-is.  It will use the last `TEdit` type declared in the `uses` clause. This is known as an "interposer class", eg:

   ```
   unit Unit2;

   interface

   uses
     Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
     Dialogs, StdCtrls;

   type
     TEdit = Class(StdCtrls.TEdit)
     public
       FAlignment: TAlignment;
       procedure SetAlignment(Value: TAlignment);
       procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
       property Alignment: TAlignment read FAlignment write SetAlignment;
     end;

   implementation

   procedure TEdit.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
   begin
     inherited CreateParams(Params);
     case Alignment of
       taLeftJustify:
         Params.Style := Params.Style or ES_LEFT and not ES_MULTILINE;
       taRightJustify:
         Params.Style := Params.Style or ES_RIGHT and not ES_MULTILINE;
       taCenter:
         Params.Style := Params.Style or ES_CENTER and not ES_MULTILINE;
     end;
   end;

   procedure TEdit.SetAlignment(Value: TAlignment);
   begin
     if FAlignment <> Value then
     begin
       FAlignment := Value;
       RecreateWnd;
     end;
   end;

   end.
   ```

Comment: or use interposer class: `TEdit = Class(Unit2.TMyEdit);` or create `TMyEdit` dynamically at runtime.

Comment: that was the answer i was looking for, thanks a ton.